# UiTableView label word wrap

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uilabel

I define with a separate UILabel Class the margin from my Label in the Cell:

```
- (void)drawTextInRect:(CGRect)rect {
    UIEdgeInsets insets = {5, 10,5, 10};
    [super drawTextInRect:UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(rect, insets)]; 
}
```

With following code, I define the height from the cell:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    if (!self.customCell) {
        self.customCell = [self.chatTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CellChat"];
    }

    self.customCell.sender.text = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    [self.customCell layoutIfNeeded];

    CGFloat height = [self.customCell.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize].height;

    return height +1; 
}
```

My question: When I test the application then it will not take the word wrap on the right place. Why? Does it have something to do with the UILabel Class?

**EDIT:**

Thanks, but I still doesn't work. I don't have an error, but when I am load the table view it does not display text. At the moment, my code looks like that:

*Imports:*

```
#import "ChatViewController.h"
#import "ChatTableViewCell.h"

@interface ChatViewController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) ChatTableViewCell *customCell;

@end
```

*Next:*

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UILabel *gettingSizeLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    gettingSizeLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:15];
    PFObject *tempObject = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    gettingSizeLabel.text = [tempObject objectForKey:@"Sender"];
    gettingSizeLabel.numberOfLines = 0;

    CGSize maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(140, MAXFLOAT);
    CGSize expectedSize = [gettingSizeLabel sizeThatFits:maximumLabelSize];

    return expectedSize.height + (10*2);
}
```

*My cellForRowAtIndexPath:*

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifer = @"CellChat";

    ChatTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifer];

    PFObject *tempObject = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.sender.text = [tempObject objectForKey:@"Sender"];
    cell.receptor.text = [tempObject objectForKey:@"Receptor"];
    cell.sender.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    cell.sender.numberOfLines = 0;

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**

Do not use `self.customCell` inside `- (CGFloat)tableView:tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath`

Instead, calculate the cell height something like this:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    UILabel *gettingSizeLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    gettingSizeLabel.font = font;
    gettingSizeLabel.text = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];  // your text inside [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    gettingSizeLabel.numberOfLines = 0;

    CGSize maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(yourMaxWidth, MAXFLOAT);

    CGSize expectedSize = [gettingSizeLabel sizeThatFits:maximumLabelSize];

    return expectedSize.height /*then add your margin 'y' margin multiplied by two for the top and bottom margin*/;
}
```

and dont forget to set

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellID = @"CellChat";

    self.customCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID];

    if (!self.customCell)
    {
        self.customCell = [[YourCellClass alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellID];
    }

    // dont forget to set this

    self.customCell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    self.customCell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    // [self.customCell sizeToFit]; optional depending from what you want
    return self.customCell;
}
```

> ***Hope this have helped you, happy coding.. Cheers! :)***

Comment: is correct. Your cell has not been initialised when heightForRowAtIndexPath is call. Its first heightForRowAtIndexPath will be call then cellForRowAtIndexPath.